# Knockout : Bind data object with select element's option

Tags: jquery, cordova, knockout.js

I am using KO MVVM for data binding along with Phonegap (running in ripple emulator), but I am facing an issue.

I am trying to bind selected value's object in select element.

My code is:

**HTML**

```
<select data-bind="options: pro(), 
                   optionsText: 'value', 
                   optionsValue: this, 
                   value: province">
</select>
```

**JS**

```
function screen1ViewModel()
{
    var self = this;
    self.pro = ko.observableArray();
    self.province = ko.observable();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var vm = new screen1ViewModel();

    var pro = [{
        "symbol": "AB",
        "value": "AB - Alberta"
    },
    {
        "symbol": "BC",
        "value": "BC - British Columbia"
    }];

$.each(pro, function(index, item) {
                vm.pro().push(item);
            });
});

console.log(vm.province().symbol);
console.log(vm.province().value);
```

For example, if I select `AB - Alberta` from select list, I need it's other keys too.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes. Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment;
Bindings value: options: pro(), optionsText: 'value', optionsValue: this, value: province

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove the `optionsValue: this,` (although strangely it is working in KO 3.0 and up [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QYfE9/))

Because the default behavior is that Knockout uses the whole object as the `value` if there is no `optionsValue` options is specified, which is exactly what you need:

```
<select data-bind="options: pro, optionsText: 'value', value: province"></select>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P9zyW/).

Comment: It was the problem of KO version. Great

Answer (score 1):

Your view model seems to be disturbed. Here is a solution

View

```
<select 
    data-bind="
        options: pro, 
        optionsText: 'value', 
        optionsValue: 'symbol', 
        optionsText: 'value'
        value: province
">
</select>
```

ViewModel

```
function screen1ViewModel()
{
    var self = this;
    self.pro = ko.observableArray();
    self.province = ko.observable();

    self.GetValue = function(){
        console.log(self.province())
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var vm = new screen1ViewModel();


    var pro = [{
        "symbol": "AB",
        "value": "AB - Alberta"
    },
    {
        "symbol": "BC",
        "value": "BC - British Columbia"
    }];

    vm.pro(pro)
    ko.applyBindings(vm)
});
```

## Demo

[Documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html)  will be helpful.

EDIT:

Modify the function

```
self.GetValue = function(){
    var obj = {}
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.pro(),function(item){
        if(item.symbol ==self.province()){
            obj = item
        }
    })
    console.log(obj)
}
```

## Demo

Comment: In this way it's working but I need "optionsValue: this" in select element, So that I can get both SYMBOL and VALUE keys (and other if any).
Thanks

Comment: So you mean there is no way to store whole object in "self.province = ko.observable()" directly. :(

Comment: @Amritpalsingh of course there is way, see it in my answer.